# how to download .exe file from sql sever database in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="download_code.aspx.cs" Inherits="download_code" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
public partial class download_code : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strQuery = "select Name, ContentType, Category, Data from Softwares where Id=@id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 19;
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        if (dt != null)
        {
            download(dt);
        }
    }
    private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
    private void download(DataTable dt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
        + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

when we download the `.exe` file using this code, it downloads the file in an unknown format rather than .exe, i have tried to download a zip file also with this code but it was unsuccessful there also

Comment: plzzzzz help me by solving my problem as soon as possible....

Comment: Just use anchor tag. Assign href as zip file. It will download zip file. Don't use exe as download file.

Comment: where would i use anchor tag?

Comment: I mean you should have download link anywhere on page. And that link points to your zip file.

Comment: plz give me the code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe "Content-Disposition" is case sensitive, so you should try...

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
```

If the file is a zip then try hardcoding the content type to be sure it is correct...

```
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
```

If the file is an exe then try

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

Comment: i tried this but it downloads zip file in xml format

Comment: What is the content type output? Maybe try hard coding to be sure it is correct, ie if a zip file...

    Response.ContentType = "application/zip";

Or if an exe file then possibly...

    Response.ContentType = "application/exe";

Or maybe...

    Response.ContentType = "application/x-msdownload";

Also make sure you have cleared your browser cache

Comment: i am fresher in asp.net so i don't know much about complex coding

Answer (score 1):

Try below,

```
<a href="1.zip">Download Zip File</a>
```

Comment: Well, there should be zip file on server. So if you make zip file from your content. It will work.